# How to compute the variance of the vertex degree in $G(n,1/2)$?

Tags: probability, variance, random-graphs

Consider the random graph $G(n,1/2)$ and let $d(v)$ be the degree of the vertex $v \in V(G)$. By considering the indicator RV $X_w$ for the evenet $\{v,w\} \in E(G)$ it is easy to see that

$$\mathbb{E}[d(v)] = \sum_{\substack{w = 1 \\ w \ne v}}^n \mathbb{E}[X_w] = \frac{n-1}{2}.$$

But I do not see how to compute the variance of $d(v)$. I know that it is supposed to be $V[d(v)] = \frac{n-1}{4}$, but when I try to prove this I do not get further than:

$$\mathbb{V}[d(v)] = \mathbb{E}[d(v)^2] - \mathbb{E}[d(v)]^2.$$

Could you please tell me how to compute $\mathbb{E}[d(v)^2]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow your lead, we have
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&d(v)=\sum_{w \not = v}X_w\\
\implies & d(v)^2=\left(\sum_{w \not = v}X_w \right)^2=\sum_{w \not = v}X_w^2+\sum_{s,t \not = v,s\not=t}X_sX_t\\
\implies & \mathbb{E}[d(v)^2]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_w^2+\sum_{s,t \not = v,s\not=t}X_sX_t\right]\\
\implies & \mathbb{E}[d(v)^2]=\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{4}=\frac{n^2-n}{4}\\
\implies& \mathbb{V}[d(v)]=\frac{n^2-n}{4}-\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}=\frac{n-1}{4}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$